# Import Product Image Sort Order Value Using Magmi Or Other Import Tool

Tags: import, magmi, dataflow, product-images, image-upload

I am looking to import multiple product images into Magento using Magmi, however I cant seem to find a way to import the product image sort order attribute along with the image. Does anybody know the easiest way to import product image positions via CSV using Magmi or dataflow profiles or any other tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The image processor is required if you wish to import images against your products. This plugin has several advanced features that are explained below.
```

This document refers to Image Attributes Processor Version 1.0.25

**Base Images**

The three base images can be imported by using the attribute names image, small_image and thumbnail

```
sku,image,small_image,thumbnail
00001,/00001.jpg,/00001small.jpg,/00001thumb.jpg
00002,/image1.jpg,/image2.jpg,/image3.jpg
```

The images will be imported from the folder defined in the "Image search path" setting shown in the configuration screen (entered after you enable the plugin)

**Image search path**

The "Image search path" field specifies the folder that your original images are stored in. The files are copied from here to the media/catalog/product image folders during the import process. This search path can be relative or absolute.

[image]
if you enter a path that does not include a leading forward slash, the value will be prefixed with the "Filesystem Path to magento directory" setting shown at the very top of the Magmi configuration screen (next to the database settings)

[image]

This normally contains the value "../.."

If you look at the two screenshots shown above, this will give a combined search path of ../../media/import

This search path is relative to your Magmi home folder (and not the Magento home folder). The image names included in your CSV file should be prefixed with a forward slash. They will directly appended to the end of the search path derived above

**Absolute server path**

Alternatively you can include a full server path for the images. To do this, include a leading forward slash when you enter the "Image search path" in the configuration screen.

> /var/www/media/import

When you include a leading forward slash, the "File system path" is not appended and the raw value you enter will be used instead.

**Note :** The path does not need to be part of your Magento directory structure. For example, the path could be /tmp – or any other location on your server hard drive.

**More Column Headers**

```
sku
description
image
attribute_set
weight
media_gallery
type
tax_class_id
qty
store
price
is_in_stock
name
thumbnail
visibility
att_eby_title
small_image
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Keyul. Your answer really helped me and with a couple of tests I worked out that Magmi will import each product image in the order that they are specified in the spreadsheet. All I had to do was put the products images in the spreadsheet in the order I wanted them to appear on the product page and it worked! :-)

Comment: @ Keyul Shah : is it possible images import from other server using " Image search path " ,